# Memory Leak in iOS KeychainItemWrapper

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-leaks, keychain

I'm using the KeyChainItemWrapper from Apple's sample code to store user password for authentication, but when I call it to set the password:

```
   [keychain setObject:passwordField.text forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
```

It dribbles memory leaks all over my shirt. The problem apparently traces back to line 274 in KeyChainItemWrapper.m, which is this:

```
if (SecItemCopyMatching((CFDictionaryRef)genericPasswordQuery, (CFTypeRef *)&attributes) == noErr)
{
```

How would I fix this, and should I be more careful when working with Apple sample code in the future?

Note: I could post more code, but I've narrowed the problem down to this line using Instruments and the full sample code is readily available to any developer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the code for [KeyChainItemWrapper](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html), I'd agree that this line is a memory leak. They missed the `[attributes release]` at the end of `writeToKeychain`. See all the other calls to `SecItemCopyMatching()` in this file for examples of how they correctly release the returned-by-reference object.

I would use the "It's good, but..." link at the bottom of this page to note the error.

Comment: That was exactly where the problem was. Just add [attributes release]; to the end of the function plugs that link. This bug has been reported to Apple as you suggested.

Comment: Wow - as far as sample code goes, I think KeychainItemWrapper is some of the worst out there! autoreleases everywhere, at least 2 known memory leaks, including the above, and another one initialising keychainItemData ...

Comment: npellow, what's wrong with autoreleases? They just release at some point. Apple uses them frequently. In fact, its how they want us to program

Answer (score 3):

Static analysis is reporting a potential leak of on object in method resetKeychainItem, line 191, of KeyChainItemWrapper.m. Surprisingly, it does not report a potential leak in the area addressed above, although I did add release of the object as suggested, and for correctness.

Here is the code with the leak being reported:

```
- (void)resetKeychainItem
{
    ...
    // Default attributes for keychain item.
    [keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(id)kSecAttrAccount]; // <-- Potential leak of an object
    [keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(id)kSecAttrLabel];
    [keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(id)kSecAttrDescription];

    // Default data for keychain item.
    [keychainItemData setObject:@"" forKey:(id)kSecValueData];
}
```

This issue is being reported on the empty string @"".  I tried a variety of code implementations to try and "fix" this issue, but nothing appears to work.

Is this is a false positive?

Update: Right after posting I realized that I can double-click on the warning to trace the error.

This warning is attributed to the line above it for allocating the dictionary:

```
if (!keychainItemData)
{
    self.keychainItemData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

I changed the code to the following:

```
if (!keychainItemData)
{
    self.keychainItemData = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

The analyzer warning is no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

I found another one leak in `- (void) resetKeychainItem`.

It should be

`self.pKeychainItemData = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];`.

Comment: why not `self.pKeychainItemData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];`? So much cleaner...